# Sharepoint Farmname and Federationname in SP2013 on prem

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, azure-ad, sharepoint-farm, federation

We are trying to connect Azure AD to our Sharepoint 2013 on premise for
SSO.

We have done some research and its looks doable. But one thing we cant find. Can someone help us with questions below?

Question:

In the Identifier box, enter a URL by using this pattern: `urn:<sharepointFarmName>:<federationName>.`

Where can we find the sharepointfarmname and federationname on our SP2013 on premise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sharepointfarmname:**
You can get it using PowerShell Command `Get-SPfarm`.
[image]

**federationName:**
FQDN of your SharePoint Server. You can get it via This PC -> Properties -> Full computer name.
[image]